# Почему удаляются значения из кортежа?

Tags: python

Почему из кортежа `fields` удаляются значения после применения функции `zip()`? Как избежать этого?

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb2 = load_workbook('sample.xlsx')
ws = wb2.active

fields = (cell.value for cell in ws['1'])

# Тут есть значения в fields
for f in fields:
    print (f)

cellsIter = iter(ws.values)
next(cellsIter)

for i in cellsIter:
    for k, v in zip(fields, i):
        pass

# В этом месте уже ничего нет в fields
for f in fields:
    print (f)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что выражение `fields = (cell.value for cell in ws['1'])` сохраняет в переменную `fields` не кортеж, а [генератор](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/). Исправьте на `fields = tuple(cell.value for cell in ws['1'])` или `fields = [cell.value for cell in ws['1']]`.

Comment: Генератор, получается, только один раз может отработать?

Comment: Да, [в следствии их сути](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/generators.html#id1).